# JQuery + scroll

Tags: jquery, прокрутка

Добрый день.

Как экраны перелистываются по 100% высоты? В середине простыни есть блок с классом `.showMenu`.

Как сделать, чтобы когда этот блок показался на экране (стал видимым, прижался к верхнему краю экрана), появился скрытый блок и, соответственно, когда блок с классом `.showMenu` исчез, убрался всплыващий блок?

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Решение http://jsfiddle.net/w5u3buwf/